# Common Lisp: creating a directory

Tags: directory, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to create a directory using common lisp. I want to first create a folder and then put my .txt .png files in that. I know that first I can create the folder externally and then using with-open-file and so on create my files inside the directory. What I want is a common lisp solution for this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
(ensure-directories-exist "/path/name/")
```

Comment: Note that the trailing slash here is important.  Without it (specifying `"/path/name"`), this would create `/path`, on the assumption that you wanted to later create a regular file called `name` (great for inline use; see second see also).

See also: [hyperspec entry for ensure-directories-exist](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ensu_1.htm), and [relevant chapter in Practical Common Lisp book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html).

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html) seems to be a nice writeup, explaining all the nuances of the file I/O issue that CL needs to address.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have multiple processes running simultaneously, who might sometimes need to line up for a program (resource) that cannot run in parallel. Then creating a directory can be an efficient way to lock the resource. `ensure-directories-exist` is not good for that because it is not atomic. In this situation I use (in sbcl)

```lisp
(sb-unix:unix-mkdir "/name/of/directory"  #o777)
```